# System Access Monitoring Software

Tags: security, monitoring

Are there any programs that you would recommend that monitor access to your computer from the network? Windows XP Professional My "monitor" I mean log system access from he network. What folders and files are accessed, if any changes are made, etc...

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: So you mean legitimate system access from the network, or illegitimate access from the network? And I assume you mean the *local* network rather than the internet, because putting an XP system on the network without a firewall is like putting a big blinking neon sign outside your door that says "please steal everything in my house".

Comment: I guess I mean any access. My computer sits on a corporate network, behind their firewall. There are files that are meant to be accessed by some users. There are also users that have no business poking around on my computer. I think I have sharing setup correctly, but I would like to be able to see if there are attempts (successful or not) to gain access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PA File Sight](http://www.poweradmin.com/file-sight) can log file and folder access.  You'd want to be sure and add your user account and possibly a few system processes to the Ignore list so they don't get logged.  Generally it's for server auditing, but it works on XP too.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is really "How do I stop people from accessing my file shares when they have no business doing so", the answer is really "Change the password, then give it only to the people who have any business accessing your shares". Or maybe the problem is that there is no password, in which case you need to set that up.

I also think that you can set up user accounts for file shares. Instead of one password for everyone, it's far more secure to create accounts with different passwords for each user. That way, when someone gives the password to someone they shouldn't, you'll know who it is that's handing out passwords.

This question probably belongs on superuser.com. Also, since this isn't a chatty kind of site, it's better to include as much information as possible when you first ask your question. State the **problem** in detail, so that people don't need to extract necessary details through lengthy back-and-forth troubleshooting.

Comment: I have sharing setup so that users that are members of select groups or only specific users have access to the folders they should. The issue is I have no control over those users. For instance a user that tells everyone their login password so others can get on their computer. What I want to be able to see is this user accessed this file from this computer at this time. I can then judge if the access was legitimate.

Comment: What is the nature of the data? Why is it so sensitive that only certain users should have it? Is this a database that people edit, or an Excel spreadsheet that acts as one? It's starting to sound like Windows File sharing isn't the right solution for the job.

Answer (score 0):

I like using `tail -f |grep ssh` myself.

Or the SSH daemon's log.

Define "monitor" and "access to your computer", and "computer" and "operating system" please.

Answer (score 0):

IBM ISS (Site protector) - IDS sensor and also Proventia server, both are very good and can not only tell who logged in but also lots of information, like any changes and at the same time it can monitor application and network vulnerabilities and attacks

Comment: if it is Linux you can always run the command "last" that will show all connected users and the last time someone connected

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-inventing the wheel, just go into your Local Security Settings control panel and enable Local Audit Policies.

Comment: I've tried this before, but it also logs access by myself the system and completely filled the events log in less than a day